# Not able to remove semi-tranparent background from the carousel

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I am working with this template and need to remove the opacity or semi-transparent background color from the owl-carousel. I tried few option but i am not able to get rid of can some one point me to the right CSS property as i cant fine it. even below cSS doesnt work

```
element {
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

http://minth.amazyne.com/v-1.7/home-version-owl-fullscreen-2-op.html#home

I want to see actual image in full colour by removing white transparent color

Comment: fount the css `.theme-background-section.fs-overlay.light::before {
 background: #fffc;
}`

Comment: The right element needs to be targeted, e.g: `.theme-background-section.fs-overlay:before`, so your selectors, with your statement declaration will look like this: `.theme-background-section.fs-overlay:before {
    background: transparent !important;
}` - an `!important` declaration has been added to *over-qualify* the more *specific* selectors of `.theme-background-section.fs-overlay.light:before`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Using `!important` usually is a bigger problem at the end. I'd suggest using a more specific selector, so it can be also overriden later even if you can't change the css files loading order. It can be really simple `body .theme-back...` override `.theme-back...` and can be overriden by `html body .theme... ` or `:root body .theme...`. Just adding the element is enough: `div.theme-back...` for the case here. [w3c css specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the RGBA value as below.

```
.theme-background-section.fs-overlay.light:before {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

Or simply:

```
.theme-background-section.fs-overlay.light:before {
    background: none;
}
```

It's always better to be more specific with your selector than to just use !important.

Comment: Is there a way i can reduce the image which are showing in the background to 80% or less, so that image shows in bottom center,slightly smaller than as it is showing now.

Comment: You could add: .theme-background-section { background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;}

Comment: Try .theme-background-section { background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: auto 80%;}